# connect list to database

Tags: list, list-view, list-form

I have customer list in sharepoint 2010 site with a column name company.

In the new item form of the customer i need dropdown list with the name of companies. The thing is i need to fetch this list of companies from database and display in dropdown list.

I know this the possible if i create a web part in visual studio but in that case i need to deploy a new list with all data to be added again ie lots of rework .

i want to avoid it . Pls suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need exactly drop down, then you can [create external list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558778.aspx) and add lookup for external list to the customers list.

Another way - create external datasource and add external datacolumn to customers list. At this point you will have entity piecker (seem to the user piecker) to choose value.

Comment: I tried adding external column but it say external content types not available.  what i need to do.

Comment: You need to create exernal content type. In the following link you will find instruction how to create external content type based on sql server table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557243.aspx